# Asynchronous file appends

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In trying to learn node.js/socket.io I have been messing around with creating a simple file uploader that takes data chunks from a client browser and reassembles on server side.

The socket.io event for receiving a chunk looks as follows:

```
socket.on('sendChunk', function (data) {
    fs.appendFile(path + fileName, data.data, function (err) {
      if (err) 
       throw err;
      console.log(data.sequence + ' - The data was appended to file ' + fileName);
    });
  });
```

The issue is that data chunks aren't necessarily appended in the order they were received due to the async calls. Typical console output looks something like this:

- 1 - The data was appended to file testfile.txt
- 3 - The data was appended to file testfile.txt
- 4 - The data was appended to file testfile.txt
- 2 - The data was appended to file testfile.txt

My question is, what is the proper way to implement this functionality in a non-blocking way but enforce sequence. I've looked at libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), but really want to be able to process each as it comes in rather than creating a series and run once all file chunks are in. I am still trying to wrap my mind around all this event driven flow, so any pointers are great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you would use a queue for the data waiting to be written, then whenever the previous append finishes, you try to write the next piece. Something like this:

```
var parts = [];
var inProgress = false;
function appendPart(data){
  parts.push(data);
  writeNextPart();
}

function writeNextPart(){
  if (inProgress || parts.length === 0) return;

  var data = parts.shift();
  inProgress = true;
  fs.appendFile(path + fileName, data.data, function (err) {
    inProgress = false;
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.sequence + ' - The data was appended to file ' + fileName);

    writeNextPart();
  });
}

socket.on('sendChunk', function (data) {
  appendPart(data);
});
```

You will need to expand this to keep a queue of `parts` and `inProgress` based on the fileName. My example assumes those will be constant for simplicity.

Comment: I like it. Any npm implementation of  this that you know of? Seems like it might be a common need to have a monitored  queue to map a given function to...

Comment: I also like it.  But in writeNextPart(), instead of doing a "parts.shift()", shouldn't there be some logic to keep track of the most recently written sequence number, and see if the next needed sequence number is available in "parts"?  I.e., if we have not yet written anything to the file and seq#2 arrives, we should just keep queuing up parts until seq#1 arrives, at which point we would process it?

Comment: @DanielChisholm Good point, I don't know. I was assuming that the parts would all be coming from the same client, and that SocketIO would preserve the order of 'sendChunk' events. If it doesn't preserve the order then that would be needed.

Comment: In this simple example they are coming from the same client, and I have been working under the assumption that socket.io preserves the order.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the appends to be in order or synchronous. You could use `fs.appendFileSync` instead of `fs.appendFile`. This is quickest way to handle it, but it hurts performance.

If you want to handle it asynchronously yourself, use streams which deal with this problem using `EventEmitter`. It turns out that the response (as well as the request) objects are streams. Create a writeable stream with `fs.createWriteStream` and write all pieces to append the file.

```
fs.createWriteStream(path, [options])#
Returns a new WriteStream object (See Writable Stream).

options is an object with the following defaults:

{ flags: 'w',
  encoding: null,
  mode: 0666 }
```

In your case you would use flags: 'a'

Comment: I actually tried appendFileSync initially just for the heck of it, for some reason random chunks of the file were missing. I am running this local and using small chunk sizes, so not sure that many simultaneous calls to append on the same file somehow clobber each other or what. With the writestream I'd still need to worry of sequencing and queuing right?